# OneSignal Android Studio failed to get Android Parameters issue

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I am trying to integrate OneSignal to my android app after successfully integrating it to iOS with no problems.
I have added android platform to my app in my OneSignal account and gone through all the steps. However, when I run the app, it just fails to get the parameters and returns `userid = null`, pushtoken is not `null`, `permissionStatus.enabled = true`, `subscriptionStatus.subscribed = false`.
I have literally tried everything since 3 days but with no luck. It doesn't event recognise in the website that any device has requested but got an error.

I have tried using simulators and real devices but it never worked. I have also tried to go to the link its trying to access through the computers browser and it gets the json data.

```
JSON Data:
"chnl_lst":[],"outcomes":{"direct":{"enabled":false},"indirect":{"notification_attribution":{"minutes_since_displayed":1440,"limit":10},"enabled":false},"unattributed":{"enabled":false}}}
```

- Environment:
  Android Studio 3.4.2 (Windows 10),
  Android Studio 3.5.1 (Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6),
  Pixel 3 XL Simulator running (Android 9, API 28),
  Pixel 2 XL Simulator running (Android 8.1, API 27),
  Huawei Honor real device running (Android 7.0, API 24),
  OneSignal.sdktype = native,
  OneSignal.VERSION = 031104

```
public class ApplicationClass extends Application {
private static Context context;

public static Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = getApplicationContext();

    // OneSignal Initialization
    OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.DEBUG, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE);
    OneSignal.startInit(this).inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification).unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
            .init();

}
```

When I connect to OneSignal this should return a userid for the current device but it just returns null. I have integrated the same app to iOS and it is working fine. Here are the error logs:

```
2019-10-06 12:15:11.498 30972-31049/com.mtm.edrequests W/OneSignal: OneSignalRestClient: null Error thrown from network stack.
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to onesignal.com/2606:4700::6810:d720 (port 443) from /fec0::1cb6:8803:6c1:556 (port 42418) after 60000ms
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:185)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:129)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:137)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:145)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:141)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:538)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalRestClient.startHTTPConnection(OneSignalRestClient.java:177)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalRestClient.access$100(OneSignalRestClient.java:44)
at com.onesignal.OneSignalRestClient$4.run(OneSignalRestClient.java:108)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-10-06 12:15:11.500 30972-31057/com.mtm.edrequests I/OneSignal: Failed to get Android parameters, trying again in 40 seconds.
2019-10-06 12:15:51.504 30972-31057/com.mtm.edrequests D/OneSignal: Starting request to get Android parameters.
```